# Protocol Buffers import message depending on another imported message

Tags: import, protocol-buffers

About import statement, google says that https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto#services :

> You can use definitions from other .proto files by importing them. To import another .proto's definitions, you add an import statement to the top of your file.
>   By default you can only use definitions from directly imported .proto files.

...Sounds great, but what about that :

1.proto :

```
message M1{
   required string foo = 1;
}
```

2.proto :

```
import "1.proto";
message M2{
    required M1 m_1 = 1;
}
```

3.proto :

```
import "2.proto";
message M3{
    required M2 m_2 = 1;
}
```

So, When parsing 3.proto, M1 shouldn't be accessible because 1.proto is not imported publicly from 2.proto.
However, M2 should be, because it is directely imported from 3.proto...

Thus what about M2.m_1 ? how a compiler should generate classes ?

Comment: Maybe with forward declaration? Try it with e.g. C++ or Java and see.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What the documentation means is that if you want to refer to `M1` in a file, you must import `1.proto`, and if you want to refer to `M2` in a file, you must import `2.proto`. You do *not* need to explicitly import implicit/transitive dependencies. It's perfectly fine to use `M2` without importing `1.proto`.

The compiler actually follows the transitive imports and reads all three files in order to generate code for `3.proto`. Moreover, in C++, `3.pb2.h` will `#include "2.pb2.h"` which will in turn `#include "1.pb2.h"`. The rule is only a syntax rule.

Why have this rule? Well, consider if you could directly use `M1` in `3.proto` without explicitly importing `1.proto`, just because you imported `2.proto` which itself imports `1.proto`. Now consider if, later on, the maintainer of `2.proto` decided to remove the field `m_1`. Now `2.proto` doesn't use `M1`, so the maintainer decides to remove the import of `1.proto`. But now `3.proto` is broken, because it was relying on the fact that `2.proto` imported `1.proto`!

This is a common problem with C++ includes. I didn't want to have the same problem in Protobufs, so I made the rule that you must explicitly import all of the files declaring the types that you explicitly use in your own file.